# How to order an array where a property is equal to another property Javascipt

Tags: javascript, sorting, treetable

I'm facing this issue, I would like to order each sub-items of my  treeTable but where the RightNeighbourTaskUUID is equal to the UUID of the other item,

So if the item is on the top, his **LeftNeighbourTaskUUID** would be null, and if the item is bottom, the **LeftNeighbourTaskUUID** would be null, and in between, each  items must be ordered where his UUID is equal to the **RightNeighbourTaskUUID** of the next item in the array

So each child item can have one uniq LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  and/or unique RightNeighbourTaskUUID, or those can be null if it's a uniq child .

Sorry about my MS Paint skills,(I've used ID and leftID and rightID in the picture just to help give a visual representation) just to help understanding how my tree Table is built

So I've made a search and sort function, where I will explore the children's and sort them if the children's length is higher than 1 , as no need to sort if the length is 1 or less

```
    //This will simply explore my children's noeuds recursively 
        ExploreAndSortChildrensInTree: function (people) {
            if (people.childrens.length > 1) {
                //Basically I want to apply sorting here 
                people.childrens = this.swap(people.childrens);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < people.childrens.length; i++) {

                if (people.childrens[i].childrens.length > 0) {
                    if (people.childrens[i].childrens.length > 1) {
//No idea why I double check length.....but anyways too much coffee already
                        people.childrens[i].childrens = this.swap(people.childrens[i].childrens);
                    }
                    this.ExploreAndSortChildrensInTree(people.childrens[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have no issues navigating threw each child items, but I'm unable to sort by swapping :

Is there a better way to simply sort each children's array based on the RightID is equal to the ID of the next one?

I've baked this function but it's so "not good" as it doesn't work in all use cases

```
swap: function (itemArr) {
        let sortedArray = [];
        let unsortedArr = _.cloneDeep(itemArr);
        let originalArray = _.sortBy(unsortedArr, o => o.LeftNeighbourTaskUUID !== null);
        sortedArray.push(originalArray[0]);
        let lastIndex = _.remove(originalArray, em => {
            return em.RightNeighbourTaskUUID === null;
        });
        for (i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
            let nextElement = _.find(originalArray, awp => {
                return awp.UUID === originalArray[i].RightNeighbourTaskUUID;
            });
            if (typeof nextElement !== 'undefined') {
                sortedArray.push(nextElement);
            }
        }
        sortedArray.push(lastIndex[0]);
    

    return sortedArray;
        },
```

Below, is a simple json data of my array

```
 [
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A",
        "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
        "Name": "I eat Potato",
        "childrens": [
          {
            "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
            "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
            "UUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC",
            "Name": "I eat A LOT Potato",
            "childrens": [
              {
                "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
                "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
                "UUID": "ABC-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC",
                "Name": "Lonely potato",
                "childrens": []
              }
            ]
          },
  {
            "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
            "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC",
            "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
            "Name": "I eat too much Potato",
            "childrens": []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4",
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
        "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
        "Name": "Consultant",
        "childrens": [
          {
            "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
            "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
            "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
            "Name": "Consultant",
            "childrens": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A",
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
        "UUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24",
        "Name": "Tesla",
        "childrens": []
      },
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24",
        "UUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A",
        "Name": "Bitcoin",
        "childrens": []
      },
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
        "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4",
        "Name": "Gestionnaire de projet",
        "childrens": []
      }
    ]
```

So my desired Output :

```
   [
  {
    "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
    "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
    "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4",
    "Name": "Gestionnaire de projet",
    "childrens": []
  },
  {
    "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
    "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A",
    "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
    "Name": "I eat Potato",
    "childrens": [
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC",
        "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
        "Name": "I eat too much Potato",
        "childrens": []
      },
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
        "UUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC",
        "Name": "I eat A LOT Potato",
        "childrens": [
          {
            "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
            "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
            "UUID": "ABC-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC",
            "Name": "Lonely potato",
            "childrens": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4",
    "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
    "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
    "Name": "Consultant",
    "childrens": [
      {
        "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
        "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
        "UUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5",
        "Name": "Consultant",
        "childrens": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5",
    "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24",
    "UUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A",
    "Name": "Bitcoin",
    "childrens": []
  },
  {
    "LeftNeighbourTaskUUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A",
    "RightNeighbourTaskUUID": null,
    "UUID": "00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24",
    "Name": "Tesla",
    "childrens": []
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: no sample data of the original array, you want to make your question hard for everyone ? You have certainly noticed this post  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: @MisterJojo Oh...sorry I forgot

Comment: @MisterJojo done with a clean I/O expectation :)

Comment: @MisterJojo Ok I've edited my sample to give a tree representation,  my recursive iterations  seems to be ok, I'm able to navigate to each children's, but I'm having difficulties sorting each array using the LeftNeighbourTaskUUID OR RightNeighbourTaskUUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```js
const child_x = 
  [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
    , Name                   : 'I eat Potato'
    } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
    , Name                   : 'Consultant'
    } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24'
    , Name                   : 'Tesla'
    } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A'
    , Name                   : 'Bitcoin'
    } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4'
    , Name                   : 'Gestionnaire de projet'
    } 
  ] 
  
const swapArrEl = (arr, x, y) =>{ arr[x] = arr.splice(y, 1, arr[x])[0] }

let ref  = 0
  , max  = child_x.length
  , key  = 'LeftNeighbourTaskUUID'
  , kVal = null
  ;
while (ref < max)
  {
  if (child_x[ref][key] !== kVal) 
  for (let i=ref +1; i<max; ++i)
    if (child_x[i][key] === kVal){ swapArrEl(child_x, ref, i); break }
  key = 'UUID'
  kVal = child_x[ref].RightNeighbourTaskUUID
  ++ref
  }

console.log( child_x )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: Nickel! I've made some unit test and it works good, I'm going to test the behavior if I have a huge list just to make sure

Answer (score 1):

the next step is just to re-use this algorithm in a recursive function :

```js
function treeOrdering( treeChilds )
  {
  let ref  = 0
    , max  = treeChilds.length
    , kVal = null
    , keyR = 'LeftNeighbourTaskUUID' // reference key
    , keyS = 'UUID'                 // search key
    ;
  while (ref < max)
    {
    if (treeChilds[ref][keyR] !== kVal) 
    for (let i=ref +1; i<max; ++i)
      if (treeChilds[i][keyR] === kVal)
        { swapArrEl(treeChilds, ref, i); break }
    kVal = treeChilds[ref][keyS]
    ++ref
    }
  for (let tCs of treeChilds) 
    if (tCs.childrens.length) treeOrdering(tCs.childrens)
  }
```

> demo code:

```js
const swapArrEl = (arr, x, y) =>{ arr[x] = arr.splice(y, 1, arr[x])[0] }

function treeOrdering( treeChilds )
  {
  let ref  = 0
    , max  = treeChilds.length
    , kVal = null
    , keyR = 'LeftNeighbourTaskUUID' // reference key
    , keyS = 'UUID'                  // search key
    ;
  while (ref < max)
    {
    if (treeChilds[ref][keyR] !== kVal) 
    for (let i=ref +1; i<max; ++i)
      if (treeChilds[i][keyR] === kVal)
        { swapArrEl(treeChilds, ref, i); break }
    kVal = treeChilds[ref][keyS]
    ++ref
    }
  for (let tCs of treeChilds) 
    if (tCs.childrens.length) treeOrdering(tCs.childrens)
  }
  
/***/
const data = 
  [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
    , Name                   : 'I eat Potato'
    , childrens : 
      [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
        , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
        , UUID                   : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC'
        , Name                   : 'I eat A LOT Potato'
        , childrens : 
          [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null
            , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
            , UUID                   : 'ABC-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC'
            , Name                   : 'Lonely potato'
            , childrens : [] 
        } ] } 
      , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null
        , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-ABC'
        , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
        , Name                   : 'I eat too much Potato'
        , childrens : [] 
    } ] } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
    , Name                   : 'Consultant'
    , childrens :                           // only one child
      [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null  
        , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
        , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
        , Name                   : 'Consultant'
        , childrens :                         // with many childs to re-order
          [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null
            , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
            , UUID                   : 'xxx1'
            , Name                   : 'xxx1'
            , childrens :
              [ { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : 'xxx_1_b'
                , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
                , UUID                   : 'xxx_1_c'
                , Name                   : 'xxx_1_c'
                , childrens : [] 
                }
              , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null
                , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : 'xxx_1_b'
                , UUID                   : 'xxx_1_a'
                , Name                   : 'xxx_1_a'
                , childrens : [] 
                }
              , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : 'xxx_1_a'
                , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : 'xxx_1_c'
                , UUID                   : 'xxx_1_b'
                , Name                   : 'xxx_1_b'
                , childrens : [] 
    } ] } ] } ] }                 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : null
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24'
    , Name                   : 'Tesla'
    , childrens : [] 
    } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4880EC5'
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-610A-1EEA-B0D7-E962CE710C24'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-610A-1EDA-ACCD-2ABD6F12CC4A'
    , Name                   : 'Bitcoin'
    , childrens : [] 
    } 
  , { LeftNeighbourTaskUUID  : null
    , RightNeighbourTaskUUID : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-69F3B4864EC5'
    , UUID                   : '00163E6A-6186-1EDA-8F8C-665581CA8EC4'
    , Name                   : 'Gestionnaire de projet'
    , childrens : [] 
    } 
  ] 
/***/

treeOrdering(data)
console.log( data )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```